# How can I model a medical scenario in an entity-relationship diagram?

Tags: database-design, erd

I am a self-taught frontend developer that is trying to go full-stack, so I am trying to teach myself data modelling by means of working on some exercises out of a database management book.

In this way, I have started creating an [entity-relationship diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsRzs.png) (ERD), for a medical scenario, that is shown bellow:

[image: ERD]

I am not quite finished as I am having some issues converting some of the relevant business rules into ERD notation. Also, when reading the business rules concerning the associations keep in mind that the entity types `Physician`, `Order`, `Diagnosis`, `Treatment`, and `Patient` are needed (because in the book they are stated as business rules and I would like to understand that specific model), and although they could probably be modeled in a different way, I am trying to understand this specific model.

#### Business scenario description

- *Physicians* diagnose any number of *Conditions* affecting a *Patient*, and a *Diagnosis* may apply to many *Patients*.
- The involved hospital records the following information: *date and time of diagnosis*, *diagnosis code*, and *description*.
- *Physicians* may order and perform any number of *Services* and *Treatments* for a *Patient*, or may not perform any *Treatment*.
- A *Treatment* or *Service* may be performed on any number of *Patients*, and a *Patient* may have *Treatments* performed or ordered by any number of *Physicians*.
- For each *Treatment* or *Service* rendered, the hospital records the following information: *Physician* ordering the *Treatment*, *treatment date*, *treatment time*, and *results*.

#### Entity Type Definitions

- *Patient*. A person who is either admitted to the hospital or is registered as an outpatient. Each patient has an identifier, the medical record number (MRN), and a name.
- *Physician* A member of the hospital medical staff who may admit patients to the hospital and who may administer medical treatments. Each physician has a physician ID and name.
- *Diagnosis*. A patient's medical condition diagnosed by a physician. Each diagnosis has a diagnosis has a diagnosis ID/code and diagnosis name. Example: 1032, STAPH FOOD POISIONING.
- *Treatment. Any test or procedure ordered by and/or performed by a pysician for a patient. Each treatment has a treatment ID/treatment code and treatment name using standard codes. Procedure codes are used for diagnostic and therapeutic procedures. Example: 1244, Chest X-Ray.
- *Order*. Any order issued by a physician for treatment and/or services such as diagnostic tests (radiology) and therapeutic procedures (physical therapy), or drugs (perscriptions). Each order has an order ID, order date, and order time.

In this manner, I was wondering if someone could look at this and derive the same ERD from the business rules I have or if I messed up the translation.

#### My considerations

- The specific issue I can not seem to wrap my head around is the existence of multiple relationships between the entity types.

  First of all, I do not even know what kind of cardinalities to put on regarding the relationship between `Order` and `Treatment`.
- Another issue for me is the multiple relationships between `Patient`, `Diagnosis` and `Physician`. Also, the same issue with `Physician`, `Patient`, and `Treament`.

  Are these perhaps suppose to be *ternary degree* relationships, and (or) contain weak entity types to make this more understandable? Like `Order` and `Treatment`, or `Treatment` and `Diagnosis` I could see one depending on another as a `Treatment` in my mind would depend on the `Diagnosis` (correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: Congratulations, you have started learning data modelling with one of the most difficult subject areas :) With regards to Order/Treatment relationship, can one order result in multiple treatments? Can a given treatment always be tracked back to a single order or might a single treatment be the result of (or attributed to) many orders? There might not be even be an order entity. In a medical data model, many to many relationships are the norm not the exception.

Comment: You need an encounter which ties all of those things together on a specific date and time.

Comment: I understand that this is what you have been given but *"a Diagnosis may apply to many Patients"* doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: @ypercube it depends on what the word "diagnosis" means.  If one asserts that "patieient X has the flue", then the diagnosis might be "has the flue".  If that's the diagnosis, then many patients could have the same diagnosis.

Comment: It looks like the book you are learning from is a good one.  I'm going to point out that you are beginning with subject matter analysis.  That's a good place to start, and a good use of the ER model.  Your questions concerning ternary relationships are good ones.  Note that these are questions concerning the true nature of the subject matter, and not questions about database design.  That is as it should be, during data analysis.  But few, if any, of us are experts in the subject matter under discussion.  For that reason, we won't be able to tell you if your answersto the issues are correct.

Comment: If I had to guess, I would guess that "Physician makes diagnosis" is in the context of a single patient.  As in "patient X has the flu".  If so, it should be a ternary relationship.  Does your book show how to model ternary relationships?

Answer (score 0):

**Consideration about multiple relationships between entities**

In real life, Patients and Physicians interact in several ways. The most obvious one is that you go to see your doctor when you're ill (that's one kind of relationship between Patient and Physician). But you, as a Patient, may refer one Physician to a friend of yours (who is also ill, and, as such a Patient), because you liked how it works. This is a ternary relationship involving *two* Patients (the referer, and the refered) and *one* Physician.

**Non-binary relationships**

Not all relationships are between two tables (such as in the previous case). Another instance: a Diagnosis is performed by a Physician to a Patient (and, you could add: at some time, in some place, after x, y and z tests, etc. as attributes to this relationship). Having one ternary relationship is *not* the same as having two relationships `Physician makes Diagnostic` and `Patient diagnosed Diagnostic`. It you ever only visited one doctor, no doubt about who diagnosed. As soon as you visit *two* doctors... *who* diagnosed *what* is much less clear.

---

This is not answering all your questions, but hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For Orders and Treatment, the relationship appears to be that a Treatment is sort of a generic description / code / entity describing a what can be done, while an Order is what *Will be or was done and to whom.* There could be 0 to many treatments ordered.

So your doctor Orders a Treatment for a Patient with the various time/date attributes. The order links your patient to your doctor and to the treatment option the doctor requests. It would have columns like: `OrderID (PK),  PatientID, DoctorID, TreatmentID, OrderDateTime, TreatmentStartDateTime TreatmentCompleteDateTime,` etc.

So your ERD should show an Orders table at the center connecting out to Patients, Treatments, and Doctors tables.

---

A patient can have 0 to many Diagnoses. But a diagnosis must be assigned by a doctor. So you won't have a Diagnosis column under patient. Instead, you'd have a `Patient-Diagnosis` table to link patients to diagnoses and to doctors. This would list the `PatientID, DiagnosisCodesID, DoctorID,` and whatever time/date values might apply (prelim date, confirmed date, etc.).

Your ERD should have a Diagnoses table at the center, connected out to Patients, DiagnosisCodes, and Doctors table.

Does this help answer your questions?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer (as more details are needed), but based on your description, I'd say that:

1. the relationship between [Physician]and [Order] should be 0/1 to many because each order is unique in terms of orderid.
2. the relationship between [Order] and [Treatment] is 0/1 to many because one order may need multiple treatments to fulfill.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to introduce additional Entities that aren't explicitly called out in the Business Rules to make your model work.  This is a normal part of translating requirements into a model.

Typically in this domain you would have an Entity that represents an Episode-of-Care.  In a Hospital, this might be called an Admission, but more generally it's the thing to which contains a set of Diagnoses, including a Primary Diagnosis, a set of Orders, Procedures, etc.